# Formato de data do Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

Eu tenho no meu active Directory local os campos pwdLastSet e lastLogon o qual estou consultando pelo SQL Server com a query abaixo:

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI,
'SELECT DisplayName,Name, adsPath, pwdLastSet, lastLogon
FROM ''LDAP://DC=teste,DC=com,DC=br'' WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' AND objectClass= ''user'' ' )
ORDER BY NAME

E na resposta ele me traz os numeros seguintes: 133455849766805724 133437441606632807.
Eu preciso exibir as informações em formato de data pt-br, entretanto não encontrei uma maneira de exibir os numeros que recebo dessa forma.

Sei que pelo CMD se executar o codigo: w32tm.exe /ntte (mais os numeros armazenados pelo Active Directory o padrão de data é exibido)

[w32tm.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB9aY.png)

Tentei as Funções do SQL:

1. Cast
2. Convert
3. DateAdd e mais algumas sem sucesso.

Eu preciso muito exibir essa data na consulta do SQL Server, se for possivel.

Alguem já passou por essa necessidade e conseguiu?

Obrigado